# Xml Schema Explorer option is not found after loading xsd file in vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I try to see xsd file in xml schema explorer using vs 2015.
But when i load it I not getting xml schema explorer option under view menu.

How to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Right click inside the .xsd file then select "Show In Xml Schema Explorer" from the menu. The XMLSchema Explorer then appears. From the drop down menu at the top right of this window you can then select "Dock" and drag the window in order to dock to the desired location. Hope this helps.